# Почему мой игрок не двигается

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Делал все по как написано в гайде, но остановился на проблеме где мой персонаж
отказывается двигаться. Перепробовал все варианты и остановился на функции `movement()`. При нажатии на клавишу меняется значение `change_x` или `change_y`, в функции `update()` конструктора это значение должно добавляться к основному значению моего персонажа `rect.x` или `rect.y`, но почему то ничего не работает.

При том что когда я меняю `change_x` или `change_y` прямо на основное значение `rect.x` или `rect.y`, то он двигается, но очень криво.

В чем может быть проблема?

[image: he is jst standing]

```
import pygame
import os
import random
import time
from settings import *

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_HEIGHT, WIN_WEIGHT))

pygame.display.set_caption("H")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Hero(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(hero_color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.pillars = None

        self.alive = True

        def update(self):
            self.rect.x += self.change_x
            block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.pill,False)
            for block in block_hit_list:
                if self.change_x > 0:
                    self.rect.right = block.rect.left
                else:
                    self.rect.left = block.rect.right

            self.rect.y += self.change_y
            block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.pill,False)
            for block in block_hit_list:
                if self.change_y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
                else:
                    self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

    **def movement(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.change_y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.change_y += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.change_x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.change_x += vel**



class Pillar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(p_color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
        

# def redrawGameWindow():
#   #p.draw(win)
#   h.draw(win)
#   pygame.display.update()
#   win.fill(background)

all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
pillar_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

pillar_cords = [
[0,0,10,600],
[590,0,10,600],
[10,0,590,10],
[0,590,600,10]
]

for coord in pillar_cords:
    pillar = Pillar(coord[0],coord[1],coord[2],coord[3])
    pillar_list.add(pillar)
    all_sprite_list.add(pillar)

player = Hero(x,y,width,height)
player.pillars = pillar_list
all_sprite_list.add(player)
#p = pillar(p_x,p_y,p_height,p_width,p_radius,p_color)
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    **player.movement()**
    win.fill(background)

    all_sprite_list.update()
    all_sprite_list.draw(win)
    
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
    #redrawGameWindow()
    

    
pygame.quit()
```

```
background = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
WIN_HEIGHT = 600
WIN_WEIGHT = 600

#hero settings
x = 110
y = 110
width = 10
height = 10
vel = 5
hero_color = (0, 255, 0)

#pillar settings
p_x = 20
p_y = 20
p_width = 10
p_height = 10
#p_radius = 5
p_color = (5, 9, 255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибки в методе `update`:

- Метод не был методом, т.к. не был объявлен на уровне класса. Табуляция важна, а у вас метод был объявлен внутри конструктора и существовал только в нем
- Неизвестный атрибут `self.pill` в `block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.pill,False)`, поменял `self.pill` на `self.pillars`

Подправил, движение есть:

```
class Hero(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(hero_color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.pillars = None

        self.alive = True

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.pillars, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.pillars, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

    def movement(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.change_y -= vel

        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.change_y += vel

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.change_x -= vel

        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.change_x += vel
```